# Return HttpStatusCode in the Response

Tags: nancy

Is there a easy way to return just a HttpStatusCode for my api? I've found a slightly more verbose way to do this

```
return Response.AsJson(new object(), HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```

I've taken a look at the `Response` class's source code and I see

```
 public static implicit operator Response(HttpStatusCode statusCode) { ... }
```

Is this what I'm looking for? If so how do I use it, what I'd really like would be able to do is

```
return Response(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can just directly return a `HttpStatusCode` from your action:

```cs
Get["/hello/"] = parameters => {
    return HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
};
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#action):

> The `Response` object declares several implicit cast operators which
>   enables an action to also return, instead of a `Response` object, any of
>   the following
>
> 1. `int` which will be interpreted as a HTTP status code of the response
> 2. `HttpStatusCode` enumerable value
> 3. `string` which will be interpreted as the body of the response
> 4. `Action<Stream>` which is a function that writes to the response stream