# Nancy : How to mimic Web API plain NotFound response?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, nancy

In Web API when you invoke

```
return NotFound();
```

It generates the following response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: ...
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 12:54:42 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

In Nancy, no matter how hard I try, I'm not able to replicate this behavior, I always get 404 green monster page.

I've implemented a new bootstrapper clearing all processors and adding only the JsonProcessor, no luck.

```
public class ApiBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            return NancyInternalConfiguration.WithOverrides(c => {
                c.ResponseProcessors.Clear();
                c.ResponseProcessors.Add(typeof(JsonProcessor));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've implemented IStatusCodeHandler and also no luck

```
public class NotFoundStatusCodeHandler : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        Tuple<string, string>[] headers = {
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Cache-Control", "no-cache"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Pragma", "no-cache"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Expires", "-1"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Content-Length", "0")
        };

        context.Response.WithStatusCode(404)
                        .WithHeaders(headers);
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19326130/2068738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Martin's answer, I searched for Nancy response types and found Nancy.HeadResponse which returns a header only response, just as Web API does. So, the final code is as follows:

```
public class NotFoundStatusCodeHandler : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        Tuple<string, string>[] headers = {
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Cache-Control", "no-cache"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Pragma", "no-cache"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Expires", "-1"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Content-Length", "0")
        };

        Response response = new Response();

        response.WithStatusCode(statusCode)
                .WithHeaders(headers)
                .WithContentType(string.Empty);

        context.Response = new HeadResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Which generates the exact same response as Web API.

One other thing I had to do was to prevent IIS from sending its own 404 error page, that came fro Paul Stovell blog post, mentioned in Martin's answer.

On Web.config add the line

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

As I keep learning Nancy, I'll probably come with a better solution. For now, I think it's good enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content type in your response to something other than HTML, as it is defaulting to

```
 Tuple<string, string>[] headers = {
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Cache-Control", "no-cache"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Pragma", "no-cache"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Expires", "-1"),
            Tuple.Create<string, string>("Content-Length", "0")
        };

            context.Response = new TextResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(headers, Formatting.Indented))
            {
                StatusCode = statusCode,
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
```

I would also recommend reading this excellent blog which describes how to output the error, based on what the client is currently asking for. http://paulstovell.com/blog/consistent-error-handling-with-nancy

Comment: thanks for the clue! The the post you've suggested is very good indeed and I'll have a detailed look as soon as I can. Meanwhile, I came up with the solution bellow.

Comment: Martin unfortunately I can't vote you up, because I've got not enough reputation. But your answer really put me on the right track. Tks